# Laravel route model binding for Blade view component

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-routing, laravel-8

In my service provider, I bind the event model in the route.

```
Route::model('event', Event::class);
```

Then I create the following route.

```
Route::view('/events/{event}/overview', 'cp.event-overview')
```

In this view, I call a blade component that looks like this.

```php
class EventHeader extends Component
{
    public $event;

    public function __construct(Event $event)
    {
        $this->event = $event;
        dd($event);
    }
}
```

The code returns an empty model (exist: false). But if I do the same and forward the route to a controller, then is it working. Are there any ways to inject the model into Blade components?

Comment: How do you pass the data to the component?

Comment: I don't pass any data. I want to make use of the depency injector. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#additional-dependencies

Comment: I would assume you can't avoid passing an instance of event to the component if you want to load the concrete model. Im not an expert in this area, but views are not in the context of route binding, that is only in the controller lifecycle

Comment: like read passing data to component <x-alert type="error" :message="$message"/> etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are calling the component in your `blade` view, you can pass the `Event` like that:

```
<event-header :event="request()->route('event')"></event-header>
```